# Trouble understanding how to get radio value when name is unknown

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, struts2

I'm newbish on Struts2 and can't find the answer to the following question online.

Here's the process I'm currently trying to create. 
First the user sends an user ID or a contract ID, and I fetch informations in my Oracle database. These informations are then showed to the user in the form of a list. Within each row, it's possible to modify one information via a radio button. The radio's value is preselected to the corresponding fetch'd value. The radio's name is a concatenation of the differents primary keys of my table (3).

No problem so far. The struggle starts now. I want to get for each row the value of the radio's name and the selected value. I found solutions for that but you need getters on the radio's name hard coded in the Java bean.

Can anyone help ?

Here is the Struts 2 form :

```
<s:form id="updateform" theme="simple" action="UpdateInterlocuteurADP">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"><s:text name="parametrage_recherche_interlocuteur_adp_form_devis" /></th>
            <th scope="col"><s:text name="parametrage_liste_interlocuteur_adp_col_interlocuteur" /></th>
            <th scope="col"><s:text name="parametrage_liste_interlocuteur_adp_col_type_alerte" /></th>
            <th scope="col"><s:text name="parametrage_liste_interlocuteur_adp_col_canal" /></th>
            <th scope="col"><s:text name="parametrage_liste_interlocuteur_adp_col_mobile" /></th>
            <th scope="col"><s:text name="parametrage_liste_interlocuteur_adp_col_email" /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <input type="hidden" name='resultSearch' value="resultatInterlocuteurADP.list">

        <s:iterator value="resultatInterlocuteurADP.list" status="resStatus">
            <tr class="result-list-row-even">
                <td align="center"><s:property value="idDevis"/></td>
                <td align="center"><s:property value="interlocuteur"/></td>
                <td align="center">
                  <s:if test="%{'SC_ALER_DERI'.equals(typeService)}">Dérive</s:if>
                  <s:if test="%{'SC_ALER_DEPA'.equals(typeService)}">Dépassement</s:if>
                <td align="center">
                    <s:radio list="canaux" value="canal" name="%{cleConcat}"/>
                </td>
                <td align="center"><s:property value="numeroMobile"/></td>
                <td align="center"><s:property value="adresseEmail"/></td>
            </tr>
        </s:iterator>
    </tbody>
</table>
</br>
<s:submit onClick="return updateButtonPressed()" theme="simple" id="ok" 
    value="%{getText('parametrage_liste_interlocuteur_adp_button_submit')}" />
```

Comment: It's not possible, hardcoded values you dismissed.

Comment: I don't understand how this is not possible. It seems to be such an important feature.

Comment: What do you mean? Which feature?

Comment: To create a dynamic list of results and not be able to use them. There has to be a way of doing this since it's used so often. :(

Comment: It's not clear how would you like to use them.